# Cannot find WD partitions although Disk Utility see them

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive, partition-recovery

I have an external harddrive *Western Digital* that is locked wioth a password using their built in solution "WD unlocker". I put in my macbook, enter the correct password. But then no disks show up. I know there are 4 partitions in there, so I go to Disk Utility and see that the computers "know they are there" since the 4 disks are greyed out. But I cannot find them.

[image]

PS. I have the ability to use another mac as well as a slow Ubuntu computer, if it cannot be solved from my macbook.

Comment: Before you try something else make sure that the My Book HDD is in good health by testing it with [WD Drive Utilities for Mac](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=qAfpYw).  What files system are those partitions formatted with?

Comment: name, format, capacity, available
    
    --------------------------------------------------
    
    wd.bootable1, Mac OS Extended, 252, 56
    
    WD-FAT32, MS-DOS (FAT), 244, NA
    
    wd.TM, Mac OS Extended, 795, NA
    
    WD2-FAT, MS-DOS (FAT), 708, NA

Comment: Have you tried to verify or repair the HFS partitions?